# Remove 1 of 2 301 redirects on wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I did some changes to my .htaccess file before installing a nice pluging to handle all http to https redirects and now I see it has 2 redirects before my home pages gets 200 status code. How do i remove 1 redirect caused by my .htaccess?

```
# BEGIN HTTPS Redirection Plugin
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
# END HTTPS Redirection Plugin

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I use Easy HTTPS (SSL) Redirection for my WP site.

I use https://httpstatus.io/ to check # of redirects and its status.

[image: 1 URL has 2 301 redirects]

Comment: The .htaccess code you've posted is standard WP. The redirects are taking place somewhere else along the line.

Comment: Yes, it's my plugin then. I thought I have to edit my .htacess

Comment: sorry i copied a wrong .htaccess. Just updated

Comment: You're seeing 2 redirects: one from HTTP to HTTPS and another from non-www to www. Seems perfectly fine to me.

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem in Wordpress and what it has worked for me is:

1. Install plugin Better Search Replace and change all the instances in the database from `http://` to `https://`
2. Delete all the code in the `.htaccess` file related to `mod_rewrite`
3. Insert in the file `functions.php` of the theme the following code:

   ```
   remove_filter('template_redirect','redirect_canonical');
   ```
4. Purge all caches

And as result I have obtained this:

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erv0D.jpg)

Comment: Item 3 on this list was exactly what we needed. We knew there was a redirect being set somewhere but couldn't find out where - thanks for sharing.